# How can I override or add an attribute to a method in a separate class so that refreshing a WCF service doesn't blow away my changes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, wcf, asp.net-core-mvc

I have many WCF services that I'm wrapping with a proxy and I use the automatically generated contract classes for each service.

I see there are some stubs (ex. `static partial void ConfigureEndpoint`) that I can put in a separate class, but I've made other contract changes that get blown away when I update/refresh the WCF service. I'm very new to C#/ASP.NET-Core for some context.

A sample change in the contract is below where I added an attribute to default the company...how can I persist this attribute somehow through WCF refreshes?

```
    [DefaultValue(Constants.DefaultCompany), Required] // I added this because I want to default a company
    public string Company
    {
        get
        {
            return this.companyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.companyField = value;
        }
    }
```

Another sample change I made was changing `public` to `internal` for this method because I don't want it displayed in Swagger and this field is a constant. When I refresh the WCF it comes back as `public`.

```
    internal string PartitionKey // I changed public to internal
    {
        get
        {
            return this.partitionKeyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.partitionKeyField = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you've added a service reference and Visual Studio generated a proxy called `MyServiceClient`. It might look a little like this:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class MyServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<MyService>
{
```

As you have found, if you modify `MyServiceClient`, your modifications will get overwritten if you refresh the service reference. To get around this, do not modify it directly. Instead, subclass it.

```
public class MyModifiedServiceClient : MyServiceClient
{
    //Make changes here
}
```

Now in the rest of your c#, instead of using `MyServiceClient`, always use `MyModifiedServiceClient`. The derived class will not get overwritten when you refresh the service reference.

Comment: I'm testing this now. It looks like I just need to copy the methods I want to hide and place `internal new` in front of them and then I can decorate them with the attributes that I want. I was hoping I could do an `override` so I could just call the base method but then I would have to modify the generated contract methods with `virtual` which would get overwritten each time unless there's an easier way. This looks like it might be the right way I should be doing it though.

Comment: So my issue seems to do with the contracts that are generated and not the client (unless I'm doing it wrong?). I've created derived contract classes so I have `MyContractX : MyContract`, but when I go to make my client request, it's saying "Type `MyContractX` was not expected" because it expects `MyContract`. So do I have to copy/paste nearly the entire generated class in order to persist changes? I've created `[Required, DefaultValue(Constants.DefaultCompany)]
        public new string Company { get { return base.Company; } set { base.Company = value; } }` in order to make the field required

Comment: It's telling me to  use `XmlInclude` to identify the unexpected types?

Comment: I don't think you can change the contracts. That would render the WCF calls invalid from the server's perspective. Why do you want to add methods to them?

Comment: Well I really just want to do 3 things. Require, Hide, and Default values of the contracts. I've tried doing `ModelMetadataType` and it only works with the `DefaultValue` attribute, but not the `Required` attribute for some reason? If I move the `Required` attribute to the actual contract, it works fine...so I think it's some weird bug? And this method was promising, but I can't figure out how I can use the contracts once modified.

Comment: Hmm.... maybe use the same class name but a different c# namespace?